# Weird page flicker on macOS 10.15.2 with chrome 79 (latest)

Tags: macos, google-chrome, catalina

I'm getting weird screen flickering on [apple.com](https://apple.com) specifically. I can't seem to find another website where chrome has this issue, it's quite weird!

I've tried running incognito so my extensions would not interfere, but it doesn't change anything. Running on an external monitor or the retina display does not change anything, happens either way. I have tested Safari and FireFox so this appears to be Chrome specific.

I've recorded my screen, please see my video, it shows what happens. Mainly around the top area near the bookmark icon and navbar

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKqssSvJwqs

Chrome version : Version 79.0.3945.130 (Official Build) (64-bit)

macOS version: 10.15.2

I understand this is a little strange. I even asked a friend with the exact same macOS version and Chrome version, he does not have that issue at all so it might not even be a bug in either.

What might cause this and how would I fix it?

Comment: That narrows it down to a Chrome issue.  You may want to try Microsoft Edge (as another test) since it’s based on the Chromium engine.

Comment: Well done - I tightened up the “ask” and I do like Edge - your answer makes perfect sense if it’s GPU specific bug or just a timing issue and not a straight bug in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after encountering a few other websites that caused me some trouble

Like any of the following (and apple.com)

- https://obsidian.md/
- https://affinity.serif.com/en-us/designer/ipad/
- https://www.windowscentral.com/how-determine-graphics-card-windows-10

I was able to fix it by enabling hardware Acceleration

Go to Chrome > Settings > Advanced > Enable Hardware Acceleration

I opened a chromium bug report https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1094727

Answer (score -2):

**Rest NVRAM/PRAM**

PRAM or Parameter Random Accessory Memory that stores system settings on your Mac devices such as settings on display, the volume of your speakers, time zone settings and many others. So, I would suggest you reset NVRAM.

1. Shut down your Mac device.
2. Press the Power Button.
3. Before the grey screen appears, press the <kbd>Command</kbd>, <kbd>Option</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>, and <kbd>R</kbd> keys all at the same time.
4. Continues pressing the keys Mac restarts and a startup sound can be heard for the second time.
5. Finally, release the Four (4) keys:  <kbd>Command</kbd>, <kbd>Option</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>, and <kbd>R</kbd> keys

If this doesn't help then at last try to:

**Reset the SMC on Mac**

First, shut down your Mac and Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd> on the left side of the built-in keyboard, then press the power button at the same time. Hold these keys and the power button for 10 seconds. Release all keys. And, Press the power button again to turn on your Mac. More detail on [Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)

**Start your Mac up in safe mode.**

You sometimes can use safe mode to identify your issue. Here is how:

Shut down your Mac

Start your Mac and immediately, press and hold the Shift key. Apple logo will appear (do not release the Shift key yet)

Then you will see the login screen (now you may release the Shift key) and login your Mac. Now you are in safe mode. Does flickering still happen?

If flickering does not happen, restart your Mac regularly (without pressing any keys). After regularly starting your Mac, does flickering come back? If not, that means that the safe mode fixed it.

Comment: Some friendly critiquing:  It's NVRAM.  PRAM was on PPC Macs and NVRAM on Intel.  There's also nothing in SMC or NVRAM that will cause a flicker in a single application on a single type of web element.  Resetting these two for every problem is based on misinformation being passed around.  Finally, Safe Mode is a diagnostic mode, not a solution - it can't fix anything.  All it will tell you is that something being normally being loaded is causing the problem.